# layout with buttons in a circle?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Its a challenge for all..
How we can put buttons in relative or linear layout or any other layout in a circle same as in this image. We can do it using xml or using code. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a Circular view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method is the layout equivalent of plotting arbitrary X and Y coordinates.

Features:

- The child objects are automatically centered in the RelativeLayout whether you use it as the top-level layout or embed it in another.
- For N images your layout contains only N+1 views.

This example layout shows how to place an ImageView in each quadrant of an XY grid with origin at the center:

[image: eclipse screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
    />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_above="@id/center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_below="@id/center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_above="@id/center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_below="@id/center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @vicky Glad to help. Is this example something that you would have liked to have found in the SDK demos or the RelativeLayout javadoc?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this could be done with a layout different then [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html). How exactly it should be done, you have to try yourself, because it is kinda tricky, but possible!

[image]

This is what I had in mind and by the way not sure on 100% but with some efforts you could set it up to be proportional - to pass on different resolutions.

Comment: @nenito.. I know its possible with absolute layout... But you know there is different screen size for different devices. So please avoid Absolute Layout

Comment: After a short thinking a find out that you could do it with [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) also, but I think you always will have problems with changing the device respectively the resolution!

Comment: For each of your buttons you have to create another UI component (think as peers UI_component+your_button) whatever you want to use. You gonna need this UI component, because it will helps you to align your buttons properly. But each of this auxiliary UI components should be align left and top into that **RelativeLayout**. I will upload an image to show you what I have in mind and to be more clearly to you.

Comment: As you see each and every button is aligned into a parent layout to its bottom and its right bounds.

Comment: Hi friends, I am also doing same  as you are talking here..I got some of good things here.. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/534/android-ui-making-an-analog-rotary-knob/
Is it make sense for us? thanks

Comment: one more idea ...can use Quick Menu at place of all these custom things...but any one have idea how to make it circular? here is link for Quick Action source code: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/comment-page-2/#comment-8815

Comment: @nenito : did u find any way to do this

Answer (score 1):

In case you copy&paste the code sample from the chosen answer, you are using Android Studio and it doesn't work, here is the solution: **Replace @id/center with @+id/center**

Hope it helps somebody. As my reputation is less than 50 I cannot add this as a comment.