# How To Create a Rotating Wheel Control?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation, image-rotation

I am trying to implement the **Rotatory wheel** in android, just like the image displayed below.I came across the tutorial from this [link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/dialview.zip). But i want to implement just as shown in the below image.The wheel consists of individual images.Does anybody have any idea regarding this implementation?? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Akash

Comment: I tried the tutorial from the link mentioned in the question in which images are drawn but i want to work with images from resource.And to handle there click events.

Comment: Check this example: [**Android SDK: Creating a Rotating Dialer**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)

Comment: @PareshMayani its same sample which i implemented from http://mindtherobot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/dialview.zip. Can u help me by sharing the code of ring/circle divided into equal parts.Rotating those divided parts & handling there click events.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android) could help. Also check [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applied on OnTouchListener on the imageView through which i got three events namely:

1. **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN**,
2. **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** &
3. **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP**.

On MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN got the angle where the users touches and on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP got the angle where user releases.

After getting difference of the two angles,rotated the image of that angle.

After rotating the image checked the quadrant through angle and maintained int variable which incremented according to the quadrant and by fulfilling the condition set the new image(the desired one).

Maintained the click event according to the value of the int variable.

Comment: @hardikjoshi i am just using the concept suggested by pareshmayani, in which you would be able to rotate the image, my requirement was to rotate the circle having different sections in the image and get the position of each section while rotating image.

Answer (score 2):

To do this from scratch, you would need a way to transform your touch coordinates, into polar coordinates (to have the rotation angle). This can be done easily like this:

```
private float cartesianToPolar(float x, float y) {
  return (float) -Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f));
}
```

To rotate the imageview, or the element you are using to display your knob, you can use a matrix like this:

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
ivRotor.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   
matrix.postRotate((float) deg, m_nWidth/2, m_nHeight/2);//getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
ivRotor.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Where deg is the angle and ivRobor is the knob imageview.

A complete working sample for Android, is available on Google code at: https://code.google.com/p/android-rotaryknob-view/

Comment: i am stuck in creating a rotatory knob which rotates 150 to 210 degree . Can you help me please   see my question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728913/how-to-create-a-custom-view-in-android

Comment: And your given code is not a View, how could i change it to a View? So that i can add it in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for this:

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
//  Button rotate;
ImageView i;
ImageView ii;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i);
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.gg);
    ii= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ii);
    ii.setImageResource(R.drawable.gg);

    // i.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
}

public void ii(View v)
{

    RotateAnimation rotate =
            //new RotateAnimation(0f,generateRandomNumber(),55f,55f);
            new RotateAnimation(0, generateRandomNumber(), 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotate.setDuration(1500);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    i.startAnimation(rotate);
    i.setRotation(generateRandomNumber());
    RotateAnimation rotate1 =
            //new RotateAnimation(0f,generateRandomNumber(),55f,55f);
            new RotateAnimation(0, 999999999, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 
 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate1.setDuration(99999);

    rotate1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    // i= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i);
    //     i.setImageResource(R.drawable.g);

    ii.startAnimation(rotate1);

/*i= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i);
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.g);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(i,"rotationY", 360f);
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
 */

   /* Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);   //required
    matrix.postRotate(generateRandomNumber());
  i.setImageMatrix(matrix);
 */




   /* Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
 R.drawable.g);
   matrix.postRotate(generateRandomNumber());

    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 
 0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    i.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);*/
}


public float generateRandomNumber() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((10000000 - 125000) + 1);

    return (float)randomNum;
}



int backpressed=0;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    backpressed++;
    if(backpressed>1)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(2000);}
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                backpressed=0;
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=".............."
    android:textColor="#00ff10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/a"

    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/i"

    />
<DigitalClock
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff0044"
    android:id="@+id/rotate"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="ii"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="powered by ashwani"
    android:textColor="#00ff10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ii"

    />
```