# Radial menu android with button click?

Tags: android, menu, custom-controls

I want to design menu like this.

I have tried animation but it does not retains position of buttons.

if any one have done this type of menu please guide me.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think [Rotatory wheel in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control) which give you perfect idea about to create this type of widget. Its also helpful for me. Also check for [This Example.](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rotary%20wheel%20in%20android%20example&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=https://github.com/VadimDev/android-seekbar-like-ipod-clickwheel&ei=_ctyULDtGpGrrAfwj4GoDQ&usg=AFQjCNEscc_GzQBsl1llVxy2f4nTL5HGbw&cad=rja)

Comment: Refer to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android) could help. Also check [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel).

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: need some help me in this..

Answer (score 9):

I recently created this circular menu to add up in my recent project. It looks like
[image]

What you need is to create a new View and draw this view, check for the user inputs (where he is touching), design a feedback mechanism, for example, in my view, if user touches any of the 5 arcs, background color changes to skyblue. Here is my code for onDrawMethod.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        px = getMeasuredWidth()/2;     
        py = getMeasuredHeight();


        initial = 144;
        finalangle = 252;

        centerCircleradius  = 30;
        middleCircleRadius = 140;




            int init, fina;
            init = 160;    
            fina = 360;
            finalOVal.set(px-middleCircleRadius-4, py-middleCircleRadius-4, px+middleCircleRadius+4, py+middleCircleRadius+4);
            middleOval.set(px-middleCircleRadius, py-middleCircleRadius, px+middleCircleRadius, py+middleCircleRadius);
            while(init<fina)
            {
                circlePaint.setColor(colors[i]);
                canvas.drawArc(finalOVal,init,10,false, circlePaint);
                i++;
                if(i>=colors.length)
                {
                    i=0;
                }
                init = init + 10;

            }



            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, 180, 180, false, pencil);

            midInitial = 180;


            i=0;

            //Creating the first Arc
            if(arcTouched[0])
            {

                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(0), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
            midInitial+=36;

            if(arcTouched[1])
            {

                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(1), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
            midInitial+=36;

            if(arcTouched[2])
            {

                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(2), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
            midInitial+=36;
            //Creatring the second Arc

            if(arcTouched[3])
            {

                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(3), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
            midInitial+=36;

            if(arcTouched[4])
            {

                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
                canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(4), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);           
            canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 40, pencil);
            canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 39, smallCircleCore);

            canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 35, bigArc);
            canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 20, smallCircleCore);

            canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 15, bigArc);
            canvas.drawLine(px-8, py-10, px+8, py-10, lineCore);

        canvas.save();
    }
```

Some reference that you might need.

bitmap -> is an arraylist that contains images

arcToched[] -> is an array that defines the background for arc, the values of this boolean array gets modified in onTouchEvent() method.

lineCore, smallCircleCore ..... are paints.

I know this isn't the best way and not professional too. I created this menu as per need. Its not scale able in a way until you change the angle calculations.

This view is highly inspired from Catch Notes Application. The only trouble I face in creating this view was to determine the arc touched. The only animation I used in here are just like again Catch Notes (the one in which circular menu extends a bit more than given size then gets back normal).

Comment: Kindly post whole class :)

Comment: i need same functionality. but i need that this menu should scroll also.means like dialer..please help me..please please

Comment: menu looks awesome.can you plz put whole code so that it can be helpful to all.

Comment: Please see this question here.
I have provided complete code in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579224/android-catch-notes-app-like-circle-menu/15752807#15752807

Comment: @Paras Good job, I suggest you add it to your Github account so you and other programmers can fork and update it.