# Using view in android application

Tags: android

In the link given,there is code for 'circular-menu' view.
I am intrested in using that in apllication.
But not getting how to add that in application.
So,please help me.

[Android Catch Notes App Like Circle Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579224/android-catch-notes-app-like-circle-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be easy:

- Search the referenced icons and put them in your res/drawable-???? folders
- Possibly change the references to their ids
- Copy the text into a new File named SmallCircleView.java in your src dir
- Add the necessary import statements
- Incorporate it in your layout

If that's not working, provide more information.

Comment: Thank you so much.Actually i had made small mistake,so it was not working.But Thank You.