# Android API Demos - ICS - RotatingButton

Tags: android, animation

I am newbie to android development and currently I am studying the 3D animation by going through the file `RotatingButton` in ApiDemos project API Level 14. In this demo A button is animating by different animation which is default in Button control from ICS level.

[Here is the link.](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/rotating-button-example-in-android/)

i can do animation like Translation, Scaling and 2D Rotation below ICS level but i don't know how to give 3D Rotation animation which is given in the following link demo.

i even tried [3D ActivitySwitcher](http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/) Demo but not getting how to assign this animation to contorls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Rotatory wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control) in android which give you perfect idea about to create this type of widget. Its also helpful for me. Also check for [This Example](https://github.com/VadimDev/android-seekbar-like-ipod-clickwheel).

Also check [this one](http://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/).