# how to create Android Custom wheel or slot machine

Tags: android

I want to create an  Custom wheel or slot machine implementation.

I need to know how will implement the following behaviours as well. The needs are

Once the user tries to scroll it will check the threshold and do scroll only if the threshold is higher than a configured threshold.

The items scroll cyclic, in a sense that, after the lastitem the wheel show the first item and so on. If there is only one item, then the wheel should fill with the single item.

Once the view is scrolled all the touch are disabled till the wheel ends.

The wheel should scroll for a specific provided time (to calculate the gift from back end and determine which item should be at the centre of the view.

When we set an item to be selected with setSelected() or setSelection() methods like in kankan wheel demo (Android wheel), the wheel should gradually decelerates to the specified position rather than immediatley stops the wheel to the that position.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control Also check out the Demo which may help you. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/dialview.zip

Comment: Check out the Rotating Wheel https://github.com/R4md4c/AndroidRotaryWheelView

Comment: thanks for reply .like this style http://i.stack.imgur.com/kchyZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [3D List Sample Demo](https://github.com/inmyfree/awsome-3D-listview) very close to your needs. Download it and check its similar that you want. By small changes you can achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.but I want to create an listview that shows 5 rows at a time. It should have middle row visible with bigger text than the other rows. The 2nd and 4th rows visible but with text smaller than middle row and the 1st and 5th visible with smaller text again. So listview looks like a wheel running..

Comment: like ... https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1462991_195599953960275_1372970357_n.jpg