# Android button with custom area

Tags: android, button, layout, view

What is the best way to create `buttons` like on image below ??

[image]

Comment: Can you eloborate your question

Comment: i need to make 4 buttons and i dont know what kind of widget i should use for it

Comment: you can place your buttons in any layout like linear/relative based on the requirement

Comment: you can use imageButtons with the background `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`inside a relative layout.

Comment: @Dyna, yes, but my buttons are in the circle position, i cant add rectangle form button

Answer (score 1):

see https://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/ or [How To Create a Rotating Wheel Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control) or this https://github.com/VadimDev/android-seekbar-like-ipod-clickwheel or just make it by yourself

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    px = getMeasuredWidth()/2;     
    py = getMeasuredHeight();


    initial = 144;
    finalangle = 252;

    centerCircleradius  = 30;
    middleCircleRadius = 140;




        int init, fina;
        init = 160;    
        fina = 360;
        finalOVal.set(px-middleCircleRadius-4, py-middleCircleRadius-4, px+middleCircleRadius+4, py+middleCircleRadius+4);
        middleOval.set(px-middleCircleRadius, py-middleCircleRadius, px+middleCircleRadius, py+middleCircleRadius);
        while(init<fina)
        {
            circlePaint.setColor(colors[i]);
            canvas.drawArc(finalOVal,init,10,false, circlePaint);
            i++;
            if(i>=colors.length)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            init = init + 10;

        }



        canvas.drawArc(middleOval, 180, 180, false, pencil);

        midInitial = 180;


        i=0;

        //Creating the first Arc
        if(arcTouched[0])
        {

            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(0), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
        midInitial+=36;

        if(arcTouched[1])
        {

            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(1), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
        midInitial+=36;

        if(arcTouched[2])
        {

            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(2), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
        midInitial+=36;
        //Creatring the second Arc

        if(arcTouched[3])
        {

            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(3), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);
        midInitial+=36;

        if(arcTouched[4])
        {

            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, arcTouchedBack);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, middleCircleBody);
            canvas.drawArc(middleOval, midInitial, 36, true, pencil);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(4), null, (putBitmapTo(midInitial, 36, 140, px, py)), null);           
        canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 40, pencil);
        canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 39, smallCircleCore);

        canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 35, bigArc);
        canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 20, smallCircleCore);

        canvas.drawCircle(px, py-10, 15, bigArc);
        canvas.drawLine(px-8, py-10, px+8, py-10, lineCore);

    canvas.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a custom component and overriding `onTouch(View, MotionEvent)`. In that method, do some basic math to check if the touch is inside a circular region, returning `true` when the method consumes the touch event.

Don't forget to allow other touch listeners to propagate by returning `false` when you don't wish to consume the touch event.

Comment: thx, if it would be a simple circle i have not a problems at all, but i need forms like around red cirle on the image

Comment: I believe I've misunderstood the question.