# How to make rotating menu

Tags: android, menu, rotation, animated

I have a question about rotating menu in android. I would like to make animated menu moving like gun cylinder.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/COb8a.png]

Where 1-6 are ImageButtons, and the buttons are rotating clockwise or countercw depending on how you touch the screen. 
I know how to place the ImageButtons etc. but i never made animated menu, always static. If you can help me i'd be very appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a very broad question...

Comment: This project can give you some ideas on how to animate buttons in a circle:https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

Answer (score 13):

I think you can do this by using

1) here is library for rotating menu https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

2) use carousel view and set z depth according to your requirement http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

3) follow this [creating a Circular view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android)

Comment: now i'm start trying these examples once if it is working for me i will update u

Comment: Wah kavi..Great Library..:-)

Answer (score 3):

The best which I have implemented is the [Circle Menu](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu).
This simple implementation of a circle menu for Android applications looks like the following screenshot ...

[image]

To download the package ...

Maven repo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.szugyi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Android-CircleMenu</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.szugyi:Android-CircleMenu:2.0.0'
```

Android-CircleMenu requires Android 4.0.

Comment: This is what i am looking for.. million thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

I was considering something similar to this myself.

Have a look into the view flipper, which can be used to switch between views with a swipe gesture, perhaps there is a way to add rotation to the entry/exit animation of the views.

http://developingandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/implementing-swipe-gesture.html

Answer (score 0):

Create your own layout extending [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and override OnMeasure and OnLayout methods. There you can position your buttons yourself. Listen for touch events in your custom layout and process this information in mentioned methods.

Have a look at [FlowLayout](http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/) implementation. It isn't what you are looking for, however it should get you started to understand what you actually need to do OnLayout and OnMeasure.

Good luck.