# Implementing Auto Rotating and User Controlled Carousel in ANDROID

Tags: android, carousel

I have been searching for AutoRotating-UserControlled Carousel frm a while.
I came across alot of tutorials and also referred sources frm Github, but found nothing relevant.
The closest relevance was from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel#ultimatefaves)

But this tutorial didnt give a smooth auto-rotating and user controlled carousel.
Being a new user I dnt have enough reputation to upload screenshot of the required thing, so pls download and run the source frm the above link and i hope u will understand my doubt .

thanks
pals

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using

1) here is library for rotating menu https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

2) use carousel view and set z depth according to your requirement http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

3) follow this [creating a Circular view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android)

and refer this [How to make rotating menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381515/how-to-make-rotating-menu)

Comment: the project here : https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout is having some problems with its propeties and the code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel is quite Huge.. can you please suggest me something else?