# Carousel view in Android

Tags: android, carousel, android-custom-view

I need to implement a Carousel View. What I have tried so far is below

This code works properly, it also shows cover flow pager effect in image gallary view. But one problem in this code is when the image shows in cover flow, that time current image seen properly but next image seen on front of current image.

How can I solve this.

Main Activity

```
package net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public final static int PAGES = 5;
    // You can choose a bigger number for LOOPS, but you know, nobody will fling
    // more than 1000 times just in order to test your "infinite" ViewPager :D 
    public final static int LOOPS = 1000; 
    public final static int FIRST_PAGE = PAGES * LOOPS / 2;
    public final static float BIG_SCALE = 1.0f;
    public final static float SMALL_SCALE = 0.7f;
    public final static float DIFF_SCALE = BIG_SCALE - SMALL_SCALE;

    private int[] musicCover = { R.drawable.cover1, R.drawable.cover2,
            R.drawable.cover3, R.drawable.cover4, R.drawable.cover5};

    public MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    public ViewPager pager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);

        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);


        // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
        // directions left and right
        pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

        // Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
        // make this at least however many pages you can see
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and 
        // previous pages will be showed
        pager.setPageMargin(-450);



    }
}
```

MyFragment

```
package net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(MainActivity context, int pos, 
            float scale)
    {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", pos);
        b.putFloat("scale", scale);
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, MyFragment.class.getName(), b);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) 
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

        int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
        /*TextView tv = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Position = " + pos);*/

        MyLinearLayout root = (MyLinearLayout) l.findViewById(R.id.root);
        float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
        root.setScaleBoth(scale);

        return l;
    }
}
```

MyLinearLayout

```
package net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private float scale = MainActivity.BIG_SCALE;

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScaleBoth(float scale)
    {
        this.scale = scale;
        this.invalidate();  // If you want to see the scale every time you set
                            // scale you need to have this line here, 
                            // invalidate() function will call onDraw(Canvas)
                            // to redraw the view for you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // The main mechanism to display scale animation, you can customize it
        // as your needs
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        canvas.scale(scale, scale, w/2, h/2);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

MyPagerAdapter

```
package net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private MyLinearLayout cur = null;
    private MyLinearLayout next = null;
    private MainActivity context;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private float scale;

    public MyPagerAdapter(MainActivity context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        // make the first pager bigger than others
        if (position == MainActivity.FIRST_PAGE)
            scale = MainActivity.BIG_SCALE;         
        else
            scale = MainActivity.SMALL_SCALE;

        position = position % MainActivity.PAGES;
        return MyFragment.newInstance(context, position, scale);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {       
        return MainActivity.PAGES * MainActivity.LOOPS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) 
    {   
        if (positionOffset >= 0f && positionOffset <= 2f)
        {

            cur = getRootView(position);
            next = getRootView(position +1);


            cur.setScaleBoth(MainActivity.BIG_SCALE 
                    - MainActivity.DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
            next.setScaleBoth(MainActivity.SMALL_SCALE 
                    + MainActivity.DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

    private MyLinearLayout getRootView(int position)
    {
        return (MyLinearLayout) 
                fm.findFragmentByTag(this.getFragmentTag(position))
                .getView().findViewById(R.id.root);
    }

    private String getFragmentTag(int position)
    {
        return "android:switcher:" + context.pager.getId() + ":" + position;
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCC"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel.MyLinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cover3"/>
    </net.leolink.android.simpleinfinitecarousel.MyLinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: follow this. there is some example links http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183538/942224

Comment: @ Sanket Kachhela i want cover flow effect not routing circle effect

Comment: let me check on my machine i update you

Comment: check this https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: your welcome,but i give a try after lunch ok..

Comment: @Kailash Dabhi ok no problem

Comment: @Kailash Dabhi apka Launch khatam ho gaya ho to answerer the question

Comment: sorry brother but couldnt found solution..:( only solution is to set zorder..

Comment: @Dhaval Shah are u solved it ?

Comment: @arul not resolve this issue

Comment: @DhavalShah u resolved this issue ?