# Rounded Circle Menu In android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create a round circle menu like this:

[image: like this]

I am using **ArcMenu Library**.
My `xml` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:arc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.capricorn.ArcMenu
        android:id="@+id/arc_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

and `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int[] ITEM_DRAWABLES = { R.drawable.composer_camera, R.drawable.composer_music,
        R.drawable.composer_place, R.drawable.composer_sleep, R.drawable.composer_thought, R.drawable.composer_with };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArcMenu menu = (ArcMenu) findViewById(R.id.arc_menu);

    ArcLayout arcLayout= new ArcLayout(this);
    arcLayout.setChildSize(50);
    arcLayout.setArc(0.0f, 300.0f); 



    final int itemCount = ITEM_DRAWABLES.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(ITEM_DRAWABLES[i]);

        final int position = i;
        menu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });// Add a menu item
    }
}


}
```

And output is not coming in rounded way.

Output coming is in this way:

[image]

Please suggest me how i can set rounded menu
I am in new in android So please help me

Comment: You have to change degrees in your ArcMenu

Comment: just get rid of `arcLayout.setChildSize(50);` and `arcLayout.setArc(0.0f, 300.0f);` and try

Comment: Thanks bro but i already used this it's not working

Comment: more library at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183538/942224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out as

```
 arcLayout.setArc(0.0f, 360.0f);
```

**EDITED:**

There is no use of your below code:

```
    ArcLayout arcLayout= new ArcLayout(this);
    arcLayout.setChildSize(50);
    arcLayout.setArc(0.0f, 300.0f);
```

You just change your layout code as below and then check

```
   <com.capricorn.ArcMenu
        android:id="@+id/arc_menu_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        arc:fromDegrees="0.0"
        arc:toDegrees="360.0"
        arc:childSize="50dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay bro but i want like [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11369687/preview1.png)

Comment: That is what i did You have to define to degree and from degree from 0.0 to 360.0 to get circular layout.

Comment: @user3145614 Check out my updated answer. Actually you are not at all setting the degrees in your ArcMenu. That is why its not showing you the result. You are just changing into `ArcLayout` not in `ArcMenu`. FYI `ArcLayout` is used to create dynamice `ArcLayout` and inside that  `ArcMenu` is created.