# Layout for representing images in a circle

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I need to set up the different ImageViews for the different smileys in the image below. Which layout should I use to achieve this.

[two muppets http://imageshack.com/a/img836/5170/lwcg.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img836/5170/lwcg.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KishanDhamat I tried using it. It is not working for the ImageViews at the angles .

Comment: [Refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13381515/2345913)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create your own view and do this in the onDraw method.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a circular layout. check [here](http://blog.mikeweng.com/2013/06/on-android-circular-style-layout.html) for tutorial.

and there is also a [library](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout). check this too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this layouts.
for circle_effect.xml

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:startColor="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="#cdcdcd" /></shape>
```

For main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_effect"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/man" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i created only half portion.

[image]