# Playing Cards type gallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

anyone have idea on gallery or view_pager which is show in the below picture.[image]

Comment: I would try to use the DDMS feature: Dump View UI Hierarchie for UI Automator

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using

1) here is library for rotating menu https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

2) use carousel view and set z depth according to your requirement http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

3) follow this [creating a Circular view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857505/creating-a-circular-view-in-android)

Comment: i want like playing cards type,have only 3 items per screen